# Missing or invalid password(s) with password parameter Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl

I try to create an user into database but I want my password to be as a parameter like that:

```
CREATE USER testuser IDENTIFIED BY ''&TESTUSER_PASSWORD''
                    DEFAULT TABLESPACE test_DATA TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp 
                    PROFILE testprofile';
```

After I run this code I receive this error: ORA-00988: missing or invalid password(s)

If I running without '':

```
CREATE USER testuser IDENTIFIED BY &TESTUSER_PASSWORD
                    DEFAULT TABLESPACE test_DATA TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp 
                    PROFILE testprofile';
```

I receive this error message: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option.

If I put the password not as a parameter everything is ok and the scrips works fine.

Comment: You can check out [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what bothers you because a substitution variable just *works* if you do it properly.

```
SQL> create user testuser
  2  identified by &testuser_password
  3  default tablespace users
  4  temporary tablespace temp
  5  profile default;
Enter value for testuser_password: abc
old   2: identified by &testuser_password
new   2: identified by abc

User created.
```